# How can I build a object type schema instead of primary type?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm trying to setup a schema for a object, eg.

```
let schema1 = buildSchema(`
type Query {
    obj1: {
      prop1: String,
      prop2: number
    }
}
`);
```

but I got sync error, how can I resolve it?

I also tried to create a customized type

```
let schema1 = buildSchema(`
  type customizedType {
    obj1: object
  }
  type Query {
    obj1: String
  }
`);
```

It is still syntax error.

Primary type is working fine.

```
let schema1 = buildSchema(`
type Query {
    obj1: String
}
`);
```

my root resolver would be something like this:

```
const root = {
    obj1: {
      prop1: "String",
      prop2: 123
    }
};
```

I'm trying to get result by follow statement.

```
let result1 = await graphql(schema1, "{ obj1 }", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I just need define a proper type.

I have root data with following:

```
const root = {
    obj1: {
      prop1: "String",
      prop2: 123
    }
};
```

Here would be my sample schema

```
let schema1 = buildSchema(`
  type obj1Type {
    prop1: String,
    prop2: number,
  }
  type Query {
    obj1: obj1Type
  }
`);
```

Then I can resolve the root data

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    let result1 = await graphql(schema1, "{ obj1 { prop1, prop2 } }", root);
    console.log("obj1", result1); 
    // {data: {obj1: {prop1: "String", prop2: 123 }}}
    // I can also get partial data
    let result1_partial = await graphql(schema1, "{ obj1 { prop1 } }", root);
    console.log("obj1 partial", result1_partial) 
    // {data: {obj1: {prop1: "String" }}}
  }
```